# Windows 10 - "we cannot sign you in"

Tags: windows-10, login

The operating system is Windows 10 Professional, version 1607. At time of writing, this should be the latest o/s, as the machine is configured to receive updates automatically.

The hardware is a nearly-new PC, just a couple of weeks old. In its first few days, the machine had a lot of software installed onto it. This has now stopped, mostly. The machine is being used rather than being built.

The machine connects to a LAN (and to the internet) through an internal Wi-fi card. This is basically connecting to specific file servers, on an as-needed basis. But the account is a local account with no mapped drives, and the computer is not part of a domain.

A few times (i.e. more than once), the computer has started up, I have entered my credentials, and the computer has responded that it "can't sign me in right now". Personal settings, desktop images, shortcuts etc. are not applied, and I am assigned a "temporary profile". This problem survives a reboot - in fact it persists until I pro-actively do something about it. I would like to know what the causes of this message can be.

Please note that I am looking for possible causes here, as I appear to be able to make the message go away, at least until the next time it happens. But knowing my "fix" might help to pinpoint the culprits. In my case, it appears that I need to log in as me, dismiss this message, create a new (local) user (just doing so through Windows Settings), to log in as that user (and to just allow Windows to configure the new account). Once this account is logged in, I log straight back out. Then I log back in as me. The first time I log in, there is no error message, but if I then restart the computer, I log in, and shortcuts etc. return. Without understanding the causes, I will willingly admit that this "fix" appears strange. The thing is, I will have this problem again a few days later, and so I want to find possible causes, in the hope of finding some underlying problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author isn't looking for us to solve their problem just understand why it happens but they don't explain the solution.  Knowing what solves the problem would explain the behavior.  Since they are not interested in a solution they should provide that information instead of making us figure it out and being unable to provide it to everyone else

Comment: @Ramhound I have attempted to explain the steps I am taking in order to stop this message from occurring, so I'd be grateful for your insight on which part of this is unclear. Similarly, to be explicit, my problem is that I don't understand why this message is happening in the first place, and I don't have a solution for that, yet.

Comment: I've added as much detail as I can to the last paragraph, but, really, unless I understand the specific lack of clarity, I'm at a loss as to how I can describe the problem any better.

Comment: I've seen this but it was a long time ago. From memory I think I thought it was network related - that you are able to sign in before the network connections were working and this made it go screwy... Sadly with this machine there was other things wrong so we reinstalled (which fixed it) so i don't have an actual solution for you. What is your "fix"?

Comment: Certainly, the computer does tend to access the network, just on an ad-hoc basis for file-sharing. But this is a local admin account and there are no mapped drives. But sometimes (rarely), when I'm logged in, I don't see the rest of the lan, so I assume there are sometimes some wifi issues.

Comment: Hmmmm...racking my brains to think what network activity there could be at login. There is a printer connected to the LAN, and although there are obviously no print jobs at that time, the account does have this printer set as its default. What this might mean in terms of network chatter, I have no idea. But I can certainly reset the printer when I next see this message, see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It did happen again. Resetting the printer had no effect, but resetting the network router might have.